# Calculate distance between camera and pixel in image

Tags: image-processing, camera, distance, pixel

Can you, please, suggest me ways of determining the distance between camera and a pixel in an image (in real world units, that is cm/m/..).

The information I have is: camera horizontal (120 degrees) and vertical (90 degrees) field of view, camera angle (-5 degrees) and the height at which the camera is placed (30 cm).

I'm not sure if this is everything I need. Please tell me what information should I have about the camera and how can I calculate the distance between camera and one pixel?

May be it isn't right to tell 'distance between camera and *pixel* ', but I guess it is clear what I mean. Please write in the comments if something isn't clear.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't get the range using one camera and one image. That's the reason we have two eyes. You may try taking few snapshots from different points of views, and try estimating the range.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you for your reply. I don't have the possibility of taking multiple snapshots because the photos are taken at high speed (camera is placed on a toy car).

Comment: You can take multiple snapshots, if it's a video camera, and you need to know when the car is going to hit something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you mean is, "how can I calculate the depth at every pixel with a single camera?" Without adding some special hardware this is not feasible, as Rotem mentioned in the comments. There are exceptions, and though I expect you may be limited in time or budget, I'll list a few.

If you want to find depths so that your toy car can avoid collisions, then you needn't assume that depth measurement is required. Google "optical flow collision avoidance" and see if that meets your needs.

If instead you want to measure depth as part of some Simultaneous Mapping and Localization (SLAM) scheme, then that's a different problem to solve. Though difficult to implement, and perhaps not remotely feasible for a toy car project, there are a few ways to measure distance using a single camera:

- Project patterns of light, preferably with one or more laser lines or laser spots, and determine depth based on how the dots diverge or converge. The Kinect version 1 operates on this principle of "structured light," though the implementation is much too complicated to reproduce completely. For a collision warning simple you can apply the same principles, only more simply. For example, if the projected light pattern on the right side of the image changes quickly, turn left! Learning how to estimate distance using structured light is a significant project to undertake, but there are plenty of references.
- Split the optical path so that one camera sensor can see two different views of the world. I'm not aware of optical splitters for tiny cameras, but they may exist. But even if you find a splitter, the difficult problem of implementing stereovision remains. Stereovision has inherent problems (see below).
- Use a different sensor, such as the somewhat iffy but small Intel R200, which will generate depth data. (http://click.intel.com/intel-realsense-developer-kit-r200.html)
- Use a time-of-flight camera. These are the types of sensors built into the Kinect version 2 and several gesture-recognition sensors. Several companies have produced or are actively developing tiny time-of-flight sensors. They will generate depth data AND provide full-color images.
- Run the car only in controlled environments.

The environment in which your toy car operates is important. If you can limit your toy car's environment to a tightly controlled one, you can limit the need to write complicated algorithms. As is true with many imaging problems, a narrowly defined problem may be straightforward to solve, whereas the general problem may be nearly impossible to solve. If you want your car to run "anywhere" (which likely isn't true), assume the problem is NOT solvable.

Even if you have an off-the-shelf depth sensor that represents the best technology available, you would still run into limitations:

- Each type of depth sensing has weaknesses. No depth sensors on the market do well with dark, shiny surfaces. (Some spot sensors do okay with dark, shiny surfaces, but area sensors don't.) Stereo sensors have problems with large, featureless regions, and also require a lot of processing power. And so on.
- Once you have a depth image, you still need to run calculations, and short of having a lot of onboard processing power this will be difficult to pull off on a toy car.
- If you have to make many compromises to use depth sensing, then you might consider just using a simpler ultrasound sensor to avoid collisions.

Good luck!